# how to access specific index within multi dimensional array?

Tags: java

I am trying to access a specific index within our multidimensional array, and equate a value to the space within that index. Specifically, I am generating a random number within the range of 1-200, and put it into said index. I am trying to do this in one method.
Here's the code I have so far:

```
// rows: array for rows
// columns: array for columns
// nums: the 2D array with {rows, columns}
// row: number of rows inputted from the user so the for loop will iterate as many times as the number of rows inputted
public void printMatrix() {
    int count = 0;
    int out;
    int in;

    do {
        for (out = 0; out < rows.length; out++); {
            for (in = 0; in < columns.length; in ++) {
                System.out.print(nums[out][in] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            count++;
        }
    } while (count < row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line should be the declaration of that array. In that code, the array it's not initialized so you could substitute `rows: array for rows` for `int[][] rows = new int[200][200];`

Also, before printing out the result nums[out][in] assign to that position of the array the result

```
for(in = 0; in < columns.length; in++)
        {
                nums[out][in] = (int) Math.random();
                System.out.print(nums[out][in] + " ");
        }
```

Comment: oh my gosh! that makes so much sense. I initialized the new array above, so i could reference it in another method for this assignment. Thank you so much! That step ended up fixing every problem:)

Answer (score 0):

on top of what Alberto said about initialization, you may want to consider change your first for loop and remove the ; at the end of it, otherwise you're only looping through the columns.

```
for(out = 0; out < rows.length; out++); //Remove the ; here
    {
        for(in = 0; in < columns.length; in++)
        {
                System.out.print(nums[out][in] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: OMG hahaha! I was wondering why it wouldn't reference the out variable, and i sat there for so long. thank you!! i wouldve never noticed.